# How to generate state flow diagrams from XML in Java?

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing, stateflow

I created webservice and I return the Response in XML format. What is the best Tool to generate State Flow diagram from XML file.?

Free tools or libraries?

Guide me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build graphs images on the fly I use [AT&T GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download.php).

You have to parse XML and generate `.gv` files before sending them to the `dot` tool.

**pros:** `.gv` files are simple text files with simple syntax, very intuitive.

**cons:** You have to install the package, with windows installer or Linux package, exists on a very large set of *nix.